# Calling and Instantiating Adapter for the Listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

list_item.java

```
  public class List_Items extends ListActivity{

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.list_item);


       ListView lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

       lv.setAdapter((ListAdapter) new ImageAndTextListAdapter(this, xxx));


      Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sync);
      btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                    // code here
                }
              }
```

ImageAndTextListAdapter.java

```
    public class ImageAndTextListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageAndText> {

//   new method
    private ListView listView;
    private AsyncImageLoader asyncImageLoader;

//constructor
public ImageAndTextListAdapter(Activity activity, List<ImageAndText> imageAndTexts) {
    super(activity, 0, imageAndTexts);

    //new method
    this.listView = listView;
    asyncImageLoader = new AsyncImageLoader();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
  //  ......

}
```

}

ImageAndText.java

```
   public class ImageAndText {
    private String imageUrl;
   private String text;

public ImageAndText(String imageUrl, String text) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.text = text;
}
public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}
public String getText() {
    return text;
}
```

}

AsyncImageLoader.java

```
  public class AsyncImageLoader {
  private HashMap<String, SoftReference<Drawable>> imageCache;
  HashMap<String, SoftReference<Drawable>> drawableMap = new HashMap<String,          SoftReference<Drawable>>();


public AsyncImageLoader() {
    //HashMap<String, SoftReference<Drawable>> drawableMap = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Drawable>>();
}

public Drawable loadDrawable(final String imageUrl, final ImageCallback imageCallback) {

    if (drawableMap.containsKey(imageUrl)) {
        SoftReference<Drawable> softReference = imageCache.get(imageUrl);
        Drawable drawable = softReference.get();
        if (drawable != null) {
            return drawable;
        }
    }
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            imageCallback.imageLoaded((Drawable) message.obj, imageUrl);
        }
    };

    //this is the new thread that download the image from url
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Drawable drawable = loadImageFromUrl(imageUrl);
            imageCache.put(imageUrl, new SoftReference<Drawable>(drawable));
            Message message = handler.obtainMessage(0, drawable);
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }.start();
    return null;
}

public static Drawable loadImageFromUrl(String url) {
      InputStream inputStream;
      try {
          inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      return Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, "src");
}

public interface ImageCallback {
    public void imageLoaded(Drawable imageDrawable, String imageUrl);
}
```

}

In this example, the listview of the list_item.java is initially empty, and it will call the ImageAndTextListAdapter which will call the web url to supply the listview row of data of image and Text dynamically.

The question I have is how to call the Adapter, lv.setAdapter((ListAdapter) new ImageAndTextListAdapter(this, xxx));  What should be xxx be? can I just do a xxx=List imageAndTexts  which list of the ImageAndText class but isn't that duplicate what's inside the ImaheAndTextListAdapter constructor?

Secondly, what should I supply inside the click routine,  public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                    // code here
                }
              }   inside the list_item.
The goal of mine is hit the button and that will initiate the action of adpater supplying all the necessary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the ImageAndTextListAdapter adapter the xxx should be a List.

Your adapter takes two parameters of a Activity, and List.

So you should create a List, and create objects of ImageAndText class to add to the list like this..

```
ImageAndText image = new ImageAndText("url","Test");
 List<ImageAndText>text;
 text.add(image); //Add the Object of ImageAndText
 ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

 //Here i supply the adapter with the text list created.
 lv.setAdapter((ListAdapter)new ImageAndTextListAdapter(Main.this, text));
```

Comment: OK, what about inside the click button function. click on that, it will initiate all the actions of filling up the list.

Comment: I will have to see more code to see what the AsyncImageLoader(); does so i can know what parameters it takes

Comment: Added, Also,   The compiler wants List<IamgeAndText>text=NULL for initialization.   And a warning saying text.add(image) NULL pointer access.   If the code excuted, then it crashed.   I think it needs init properly.